# How can I create a level graph UI in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image: UI Example]

I am trying to create a level graph as given in image which changes on level up or down. I not sure what is the right way to achieve this.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you mean that pink curve the only way is a `CustomPaint`

Comment: I'm trying it with custom paint only, but not sure how to change the color on level up or down.

Comment: you may read [Path](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path-class.html) official documentation then

Answer (score -1):

A combination of `Stack` and `CustomPaint` might do the trick, check boxes can be `Containers` in-front of separate `CustomPaint` so you can change the color of each one depending on the user level.